# Inductive proof of a formula for Fibonacci numbers

Tags: induction, fibonacci-numbers

May someone help me? I am trying to use induction to prove that the formula for finding the $n$-th term of the Fibonacci sequence is:

$$F_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}⋅\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n-\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}⋅\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n.$$

I tried to put $n=1$ into the equation and prove that if $n=1$ works then $n=2$ works and it should work for any number, but it didn't work. I need to prove that this formula gives the $n$th Fibonacci number.

Comment: Have you done anything yourself yet?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: This is not the best written proof I've seen, but it should be good enough for you.
http://www.csee.wvu.edu/~ksmani/courses/fa04/at/qen/fib.pdf

Comment: You are a new user, so you may be surprised why your question was downvoted and flagged for closing. It is because you showed no effort to answer your question alone, and also you have been completely unresponsive to any answers since you asked the question.

Comment: Hint: Show that $F_{n+1}=F_n+F_{n-1}$ and then use the induction hypothesis.

Comment: "$\sqrt(1+5\sqrt{2})n$" seems very strange.

Answer (score 9):

Let $\phi=\dfrac{\sqrt{5}+1}2$ and note that $\phi^{-1} =\dfrac 1\phi= \dfrac{\sqrt{5}-1}2$.

Note also that $1+\dfrac 1\phi=\phi$ and $1-\phi=-\dfrac 1\phi$.

From your formula,

$$F_n = \frac 1{\sqrt{5}}\left[\phi^n-(-\frac 1\phi)^n \right]$$

For $n=k$ and $n=k-1$,
$$\begin{align}
F_k &= \frac 1{\sqrt{5}}\left[\phi^k-(-\frac 1\phi)^k \right]\\
F_{k-1} &= \frac 1{\sqrt{5}}\left[\phi^{k-1}-(-\frac 1\phi)^{k-1} \right]\\
&=\frac 1{\sqrt{5}} \left[\phi^k \cdot \frac 1\phi -(-\frac 1\phi)^k \cdot (-\phi)\right]\\
\end{align}$$
Hence,

$$\begin{align}
F_{k+1}&=F_{k}+F_{k-1}\\
&=\frac 1{\sqrt{5}} \left[\phi^k \cdot \left( 1+\frac 1\phi \right) 
-(-\frac 1\phi)^k \cdot \left( 1-\phi \right)\right]\\
&=\frac 1{\sqrt{5}} \left[\phi^k \cdot \phi 
-(-\frac 1\phi)^k \cdot \left( -\frac 1\phi \right)\right]\\
&=\frac 1{\sqrt{5}} \left[\phi^{k+1}-(-\frac 1\phi)^{k+1} \right]
\end{align}$$

i.e. if formula is true for $n=k-1$ and $n=k$, it is also true for $n=k+1$.

For $n=0$ and $n=1$, $F_0=0$ and $F_1=1$ respectively. 
Hence $F_2=F_0+F_1=1$. 
It can easily be shown that the formula is true for $n=2$.

Hence, by induction, formula is true for all positive integer $n\geq 2$.

Comment: You're welcome :)

Answer (score 4):

Proof: Let n=1 thus,
\begin{align*}
F_1&=\frac{(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2})^{1}-(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2})^{1}}{\sqrt{5}}\\
&=\frac{\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}-\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}}{\sqrt{5}}\\
&=\frac{\frac{1+\sqrt{5}-1+\sqrt{5}}{2}}{\sqrt{5}}\\
&=\frac{\frac{\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{5}}{2}}{\sqrt{5}}\\
&=\frac{\frac{2\sqrt{5}}{2}}{\sqrt{5}}\\
&=\frac{{\sqrt{5}}}{\sqrt{5}}\\
&=1
\end{align*}
Suppose
\begin{equation}
F_k=\frac{(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2})^{k}-(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2})^{k}}{\sqrt{5}}
\end{equation}
Also $F(k+1)=F(k)+F(k-1)$
\begin{align*}
F(k)+F(k-1)&=\frac{(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2})^{k}-(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2})^{k}}{\sqrt{5}}+\frac{(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2})^{k-1}-(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2})^{k-1}}{\sqrt{5}}\\
&=\frac{(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2})^{k}+(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2})^{k-1}-(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2})^{k}-(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2})^{k-1}}{\sqrt{5}}\\
&=\frac{((\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2})+1)(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2})^{k-1}-((\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2})+1)(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2})^{k-1}}{\sqrt{5}}\\
&=\frac{((\frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2}))(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2})^{k-1}-((\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}))(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2})^{k-1}}{\sqrt{5}}\\
&=\frac{((\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2})^{2})(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2})^{k-1}-((\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2})^{2})(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2})^{k-1}}{\sqrt{5}}\\
&=\frac{(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2})^{k+1}-(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2})^{k+1}}{\sqrt{5}}\hfill 
\end{align*}

Comment: This is a good proof but you should have two bases cases $F_1$ and $F_0$ for the inductive step to work. I.e. at the moment you can not prove $F_2$ is true as it relies upon $F_1$ and $F_0$ being true.

Comment: @IanMiller Is that way the inductive hypothesis has an "also", because it is two inductive hypotheses?

Answer (score 1):

By denoting with
$$\sigma = \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2},\qquad \bar{\sigma}=\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}$$
we have that $\sigma,\bar{\sigma}$ are the roots of the polynomial $x^2-x-1$. This gives:
$$\sigma^2 = \sigma+1,\qquad  \sigma^{n+2}=\sigma^{n+1}+\sigma^n,$$
$$\bar{\sigma}^2 = \bar{\sigma}+1,\qquad  \bar{\sigma}^{n+2}=\bar{\sigma}^{n+1}+\bar{\sigma}^n,$$
hence *any* sequence $\{a_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ defined by:
$$ a_n = k_0 \,\sigma^n + k_1\, \bar{\sigma}^n $$
satisfies the recurrence relation:
$$ a_{n+2} = a_{n+1} + a_n.$$
You just have to check that with the choices $k_0=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}},k_1=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}$ we have:
$$ a_0=F_0=0,\qquad a_1=F_1=1,$$
since this condition implies $a_n=F_n$ **by induction**.

The spirit is the same of the Cauchy-Lipshitz theorem: the same differential equation (the same recurrence relation) and the same boundary conditions (the same starting values) give the same function (sequence).

Comment: This does not answer the original question. It does not show to the OP how to use induction (which seems to be his question).

Comment: @5xum: On my planet, proving that $$a_n=F_n,a_{n+1}=F_{n+1}\quad\Longrightarrow\quad a_{n+2}=F_{n+2}$$ (provided that $a_{n+2}=a_{n+1}+a_n$) *is* using induction in the most natural way.

Comment: Regardless of whether this is induction, learning shouldn't stop once the exercise has been completed within the homework's arbitrary rules.  It's good to be exposed to many different solutions.