# Proof by Induction Using Fibonacci -- Not Sure About Other Question's Answers

Tags: induction

Here was my previous question: [Proof by Induction Using Fibonacci numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1460614/proof-by-induction-using-fibonacci-numbers?noredirect=1#comment2974637_1460614)

There was a similar one in existence already over here: [Inductive proof of a formula for Fibonacci numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/886978/inductive-proof-of-a-formula-for-fibonacci-numbers)

The one that was answered already had a decent answer but it isn't as detailed as I wish it could be.

hypergeometric mentioned this in his/her answer:

"Note also that 1+1/ϕ=ϕ and 1−ϕ=−1/ϕ."

However, I don't know where this was obtained. Everything else I can see, but this is not immediately clear to me. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You know that $\phi$ satisfies $\phi^2 = \phi+1$, so you just have to divide each side by $\phi$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is clear that $$1+\frac{1}{\phi}=1+\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}=\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2}=\phi$$.

Similarly $$1-\phi=1-\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2}=-\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}=-\frac{1}{\phi}$$.

Comment: Yes, now I see it. I did the math wrong originally when I tried going through with the induction myself.