# Characteristic equation and closed form on Fibonacci equation

Tags: recurrence-relations, fibonacci-numbers

Recently I am working on recurrence relation and I have gathered the following.

1. Fibonacci sequence
2. Solving linear homogeneous recurrence relation by characteristics equation

So I attempted to work on the closed form of Fibonacci sequence by myself. However, it seems to contradict to another source attached below indicating the closed form of Fibonacci sequence. May I know what's wrong?

Solution technique:

1. Establish the characteristics equation and its roots.
   $$r^2-r-1=0$$
   $$r=\frac{1\pm\sqrt5}{2}$$
2. Assume $f_n=c_1r_1^n+c_2r_2^n$, where $r_1$ and $r_2$ are distinct roots in this case.
3. Find $c_1,\;c_2$
   $$r_1=\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2},\;r_2=\frac{1-\sqrt5}{2}$$
   $$f_0=c_1r_1^0+c_2r_2^0=c_1+c_2=1$$
   $$f_1=c_1r_1^1+c_2r_2^1=c_1r_1+c_2r_2=2$$
   $$\left[\begin{array}{cc|c}1&1&1\\\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2}&\frac{1-\sqrt5}{2}&2\end{array}\right]=\cdots=\left[\begin{array}{cc|c}1&0&\frac{5+3\sqrt5}{10}\\0&1&\frac{5-3\sqrt5}{10}\end{array}\right] $$
   $c_1\neq\frac{1}{\sqrt5},\;c_2\neq-\frac{1}{\sqrt5}$ as indicated in the below closed form, what's wrong in my derivation?

[The closed form I would like to replicate using characteristic equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/886978/inductive-proof-of-a-formula-for-fibonacci-numbers)

Comment: What number is $f_1$?

Comment: I am not sure whether is $f_0=1$ or $f_0=0$...May I know the convention also?

Comment: Usually $f_0$ is taken to be $0$ and $f_1=f_2=1$

Comment: I think we should have $\{\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}⋅\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n,\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}⋅\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n\}$ with $n=2$ in the first row and $n=3$ in the second row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual convention is $f_0=0, f_1=f_2=1$.  Using your equations
$$c_1+c_2=0\\c_1r_1+c_2r_2=1\\
c_1\frac{1+\sqrt 5}2+c_2\frac{1-\sqrt 5}2=1\\
\frac {\sqrt 5}2(c_1-c_2)=1\\
c_1=\frac 1{\sqrt 5}\\c_2=-\frac 1{\sqrt 5}$$